# In App Purchase is not appearing on AppStore version on iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We're are currently having issues with our app being rejected because the AppStore reviewer can't see our in-app purchases. We can't seem to find why this is occurring. Does the in-app purchases have to be approved before the app. Though this is a new release of the app, not an update. When we run in development mode, it works perfectly fine. The bundle identifier isn't different for development or app store version. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Could you show the message from Apple?

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes Connect you need to submit your In App Purchases of the app for the review.

When you are selecting option 'Ready to upload binary', then you should see options to submit new in app purchases, turn them on and upload your binary. (in the "In-App Purchases" section use the link "Manage In-App Purchase" and select all those IAP's which are to be reviewed).